# How can I log each IP address that attempted to login with each user?

Tags: php, mysql

as title says I'm trying to find a way to log each IP Address that attempted to login, this applies to each user. Using PHP and MYSQL

## Let me explain in detail with an example:

IP: **1.1.1.1** attemps to log in on user "**Charlie123**", independently of the result I want to store it's IP like this:

User: **Charlie123** - IP **1.1.1.1**

Then there is another one with IP: **2.2.2.2** that attempts to log in on the same user, again independently of the result, I want to store it's IP like this (remember we already stored the first IP before)
User: **Charlie123** - IP **1.1.1.1**, **2.2.2.2**

And so on for every attempt on every IP.
This way I can easily search for X user and find every IP he/she used.

## What I know:

I know how to retrieve's user IP based on a POST, and I know how to store it on a DB. The problem is that I don't know how to make this without ruining the DB because of too many columns / too many characters.

## What I tried (in my mind):

Using the table that contains the accounts (username and password) adding a column that will store IPS separated with a ",". This fails because I will reach a HUGE amount of characters on that column and I don't think that's possible nor right.

Making a new table that will contain 1 column for User and 1 Column for each IP. This fails because it will reach a HUGE amount of columns and again, I don't think this is the way to do something like this, imagine waking up and having 1000000 columns in a table where half of them are empty.

Please correct me if I'm wrong on what I wrote here.

## Why Ip address?

To be honest I'm starting with IPs to be sure that everything works as expected and that my idea is not wrong. This can be extended to logging the computer that tried to log in, which browser the user used, etc.
For now I will stick with only 1 value, IPs.

## What kind of answers do I need:

Any way to achieve this, any example, pseudo-code, code, anything works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My answer was a new table with UserID and IP , it's the correct way to do it, so you don't mess with the Users table and you can extend it later. If the question is about database performance you could regularly clean out old entries in the new table. If you only query the new table occasionally it doesn't really matter how many rows (to an extent)

Comment: Making a new table make sense for me. I hate when I find commas in a single row. Its much harder to manage. Databases are ready to manage million of rows

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's say I manually check it every weekend by using phpmyadmin. What would happen if I have around 100 users and I log each login attempt (let's say I will check if the same IP already exists in the table before writing it) will that hurt the performance a lot? I'm new to big DBs.

Comment: BTW, is there a possible way to have all the IPS for each user on the same row? Like in my example in the question where the IPs for User **Charlie123** are shown on the same row.
Or should I make 1 row for each login attempt (having 2 columns: IP and UserID)

Comment: No, you would access using a query like: `select * from login_history where user_id = 10` This query would select the logins of an specific user. In case you would access this data from the own code, the returned data would be an array, that is easy to manage and read. If you use commas you would have to split the string... much worse. A row for each ip is the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a new table is the right answer, but "1 Column for each IP." is wrong, don't save different ip to columns, save them to different rows like this:

[mysql table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5e5d.jpg)

and search it by:

```
select * from login_history order by created_at desc limit 10;
```

[query result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBhAz.jpg)

or may be someone change there username, you can use this sql to check their new username:

```
select u.username, lh.ipv4, lh.created_at from `user` u left join `login_history` lh ON u.id=lh.uid order by created_at desc limit 10;
```

[query result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7psI.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

keeping track of user login attempts from different IP addresses
    will not result in a huge number of blank records if managed with
    proper validation before inserting the records. In most places where
    engineers need to track every user interaction a NoSQL database
    solution like mongo will be preferred over MySQL or other RDBMS.

```
However, If you use RDBMS approach:

1. Create a recent login_attempts table with username, ip_address, timestamp
2. Add check constraints on ip_address so that only valid IP addresses can be added.
3. Create a unique key of username and ip_address if duplicate records are found replace the current entry an insert the old record
    into an archives tables with the old username, IP, timestamp.
4. Write a shell script to get periodically rid of stale data and keep the recent login attempts table clean.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar. I created three columns, one for primary key, another one for user name and one for ip address.

```
    create table sample (sno int(9) auto_increment, username varchar(80), ipaddress varchar(15), primary key(sno))
```

Each time a login is attempted, im filling in the username and ip address in the table.

```
    insert into sample (username, ipaddress) values ('abc', '1.1.1.1');
```

So if i want to check login attempts based on user name, i just run a query with username and if i want to check attempt with ip address, i run a query with ip address.

```
    select * from sample where username = 'abc'
    select * from sample where ipaddress = '1.1.1.1'
```

To get the desired results, i.e., ip addresses seperated with comma, I just use the php function to loop through the set of rows and append the string (ip address)

To  append ipaddress, something like this will help in php

```
    $res // initial variable that holds username string 
    $query = //mysql query result
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $res = $res.' comma or space etc '.$r['ipaddress'];
    }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Do you run into the problem that the column contains a lot of IPs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I mean that if I want to have each IP used on that user, (let's say that 1 month later there are 100 different IPs for each user) that would make the IP column have around 1300 characters for each user, wouldn't that break the DB or something?